# Tengo un problema con los Multihilos

Tags: java, hilos, semaphore

Nos han mandado realizar un ejercicio de Multihilos, el cuál tengo medio resuelto pero no se ejecuta de la forma que tiene que hacer. Dejo el enunciado y las clases por aqui:

> En una explotación familiar existe un gallinero que solo tiene 5 gallinas. Cada gallina tiene buscado un sitio específico donde pone sus huevos que no es compartido con el resto de las gallinas. Cada gallina pone solo un huevo al día, pero lo pone aleatoriamente a cualquier hora. Si llega al sitio de puesta y el huevo del día anterior está sin recoger, antes de poner el nuevo huevo, empuja con el pico el huevo existente y lo rompe. El granjero recoge los huevos de las gallinas todos los días justamente a las 12 del mediodía.
>
> Codificar un programa que represente la actividad de la explotación en 1 mes (30 días) mostrando la máxima información posible de todos los procesos. Además, mostrar el número de huevos totales que ha recogido el granjero y cuántos ha perdido por solo recogerlos 1 vez al día.
>
> [Nota: a efectos de codificación 1 día son 24 milisegundos].
>
> Las gallinas tienen que ser diferentes no puede ser el mismo objeto gallina.

Esta clase gestiona los hilos:

```java
public class GestorGranja {
    
    private Semaphore semaforoGranjero, semaforoGallina;
    private int huevos;
    private int huevosRotos;
    private int huevosRecogidos;
    private String nombreGallina;
    
    public GestorGranja(Semaphore semaforoGallina, Semaphore semaforoGranjero) {
        this.semaforoGallina = semaforoGallina;
        this.semaforoGranjero = semaforoGranjero;
        huevos = 0;
        huevosRotos = 0;
        huevosRecogidos = 0;
    }
    
    public void ponerHuevos(String nombreGallina) {
        try {
            semaforoGallina.acquire();
            int tiempo = (int) (Math.random()*24);
            System.out.println("Tiempo poner huevo " + tiempo);
            Thread.sleep(tiempo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (huevos == 1) {
            huevos = 0;
            huevosRotos++;
            System.out.println("Huevo roto por la " + nombreGallina + ".");
            System.out.println("El granjero a perdido " + huevosRotos + " huevos.");
            huevos++;
            System.out.println("Huevo puesto.");
            System.out.println(huevos + " huevos.");
            semaforoGranjero.release();
        }
        else {
            huevos++;
            System.out.println(nombreGallina + " ha puesto un huevo.");
            System.out.println(huevos + " huevos.");
            semaforoGranjero.release();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void recogerHuevos() {
        int primeraRecogida = 12;
        int tiempo = 0;
        try {
            semaforoGranjero.acquire();
            if (primeraRecogida == 12) {
                primeraRecogida=0;
                tiempo = 12;
                System.out.println("Tiempo de recogida "+ tiempo);
                Thread.sleep(tiempo);
                
            }
            else {
                tiempo = 24;
                System.out.println("Tiempo de recogida " + tiempo);
                Thread.sleep(tiempo);
            }                       
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        huevosRecogidos= huevosRecogidos + huevos;
        System.out.println("Huevos recogidos "+ huevos);
        System.out.println("Huevos en total recogidos "+ huevosRecogidos);
        huevos = 0;
        semaforoGallina.release();
    }
}
```

Estas Clases son las de los hilos:

```java
public class Granjero extends Thread {

    private GestorGranja gg;
    
    public Granjero(GestorGranja gg) {
        this.gg = gg;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i<30 ; i++) {
            gg.recogerHuevos();
            System.out.println(i + " veces.");
        }
    }
}



public class Gallina extends Thread {
    
    private GestorGranja gg;
    private String nombre;
    
    public Gallina(GestorGranja gg, String nombre) {
        this.gg = gg;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i<30 ; i++) {
            gg.ponerHuevos(nombre);
            System.out.println(i+" veces.");    
        }
    }
}
```

Y esta es la Clase `Main`:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Semaphore semaforoGallinas = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore semaforoGranjero = new Semaphore(0);
        
        GestorGranja gg = new GestorGranja(semaforoGallinas,semaforoGranjero);
        
        Thread hiloGranjero = new Granjero(gg);
        
        hiloGranjero.start();

        for (int i = 1; i<=5 ; i++) {
            new Gallina(gg, "Gallina " + i).start();
        }       
    }
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZQsV.png): [image: Muestra de Ejecución]

> La cosa es que se me ejecuta el hilo gallina y después el granjero y quiero
> que se me ejecute 5 veces el hilo gallina y 1 el granjero, y así >sucesivamente 30 veces.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y el problema es???

Comment: "pero no se ejecuta de la forma que tiene que hacer" entonces, que hace, que se supone que tiene que hacer, donde esta el problema?

Comment: El problema está en que al ejecutar el programa solo una gallina pone un huevo antes de que el granjero pase y el tema es que deberían de poner de 1 a 5 gallinas (aleatoriamente) huevos y luego que pasara el granjero.